# iPad UISplitViewController doesn't forward the -prepareForSegue:sender method

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, message-forwarding

I have a UISplitViewController but my delegate class doesn't ever get the -prepareForSegue:sender message. I've confirmed this is the case because I subclassed UISplitViewController and it's was preparing for every freaking segue it was orchestrating.

Is there any better way to get around this, save for subclassing UISplitViewController just to forward one message...?